# Is it possible to get looggedin user email id from linkedin rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linkedin-api

I am using the following gem to connect and get details from linkedin

gem 'linkedin', :git => "git://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin.git"

is it possible to get authenticated user's email id or the id by which he/she logges in to..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to get the email address of a LinkedIn user via the API at this time.

-Jeremy